# Highcharts is much slower rendering a chart after building object vs manually coding same object

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The page accepts input from user where they paste '|' delimitated data.  This data is parsed into a newSeries object. After all the parsing is done the timing to render the graph is almost 15 seconds.  However if I copy the exact same newSeries object (using chrome dev tools) and manually define the object the rendering only takes 200ms.  Also the interaction of the chart is almost useless after the parsed newSeries object while the manually defined object interacts perfectly.

I really don't understand this.  The newSeries object is the exact same in both cases.  Is there some caching, or memory fragmentation concept that I'm missing?

Also I tried both the boost.js and the regular highcharts.js and both have similar timings.

Timings from parsed newSeries Object:

```
:246 Creating chart variable: 0.055ms
:257 Adding series: 0: 12416.308ms
:257 Adding series: 1: 335.028ms
:257 Adding series: 2: 300.123ms
:257 Adding series: 3: 319.647ms
:257 Adding series: 4: 341.969ms
:257 Adding series: 5: 344.129ms
:257 Adding series: 6: 336.129ms
:259 Adding All Chart Objects to Chart: 14393.966ms
```

Timings from manually defined newSeries:

```
:1477 Creating chart variable: 0.099ms
:1488 Adding series: 0: 66.618ms
:1488 Adding series: 1: 18.614ms
:1488 Adding series: 2: 22.586ms
:1488 Adding series: 3: 19.240ms
:1488 Adding series: 4: 27.198ms
:1488 Adding series: 5: 24.221ms
:1488 Adding series: 6: 25.175ms
:1490 Adding All Chart Objects to Chart: 204.273ms
```

Highcharts code:

```
$('#cpuGraph').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            zoomType: 'x',
            animation: false,
            shadow: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                animation: false,
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            animation: false,
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '%',
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
                padding: 0
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: times
        },
        yAxis: {
            max: 100,
            min: 0
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Trimmed Highcharts drawing points'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Using the experimental Highcharts Boost module'
        }

    });

    console.time('Creating chart variable');
    var chart = $('#cpuGraph').highcharts();
    console.timeEnd('Creating chart variable');

    console.time('Adding All Chart Objects to Chart');
    $.each(newSeries, function(i){
        console.time("Adding series: " + i);
        chart.addSeries(newSeries[i]);
        console.timeEnd("Adding series: " + i);
    });
    console.timeEnd('Adding All Chart Objects to Chart');
```

Comment: What does your code look like that takes the user input data and parse into `newSeries`?

Comment: Thats the thing, it shouldn't matter right?  If I directly copy and paste the object from the parsed data and hard code it then the hard coded works, doesnt that mean the object is right?

regardless, here's the fiddle.  

https://jsfiddle.net/kfsw52gf/

Comment: Of course it matters - your parsed out data is already parsed and the user input data has to be parsed. I do not see any pipe delimited data in your fiddle. What is your code you are using to parse the user input data into the series data?

Comment: finally got a reproduction! copy paste from data jsfiddle into repro. 
repro
https://jsfiddle.net/6gbcdb4L/5/
Data
https://jsfiddle.net/j54rdqto/

Comment: Okay, look at your parse code from the user entered text. That is complex. Look at the text you are trying to parse - that is a very complex blob of text. So, of course this parsing is going to take longer than having the data already parsed. This is not really a highcharts issue; this is an issue on having to parse a really complex string into a JSON array. You may want to re-evaluate the business rules guiding this method.

Comment: Already fixed now. I don't know why people say "it's obviously the parser". Attention to detail please. I clearly state that all of the parsing is done previous to calling any of the Highcharts graph JS. I'm measuring from Time to start Highcharts to end. Not including parsing.

Comment: The timings I am seeing are: (index):260 Adding series: 0: 21773.071ms
(index):260 Adding series: 1: 15022.416ms
(index):260 Adding series: 2: 983.264ms
(index):260 Adding series: 3: 981.209ms
(index):260 Adding series: 4: 981.593ms
(index):260 Adding series: 5: 981.614ms
(index):260 Adding series: 6: 976.891ms
(index):262 Adding All Chart Objects to Chart: 41700.678ms
(index):266 Redraw chart with all objects: 488.744ms

Comment: And that's all Highcharts. Adding series is a Highcharts function to add a series to the graph. All of the data is already populated before this. It's now looping through the series array adding data.

Comment: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries: " Note that this method should never be used when adding data synchronously at chart render time, as it adds expense to the calculations and rendering. When adding data at the same time as the chart is initiated, add the series as a configuration option instead." Have you tried to generate the `series` elements and then add to chart before rendering chart?

Comment: Thanks for doing the research! I reached out to the Highcharts folks via github and there's no way to do this when you don't know the number of series that are going to be graphed.  It's pretty unfortunate really. I wish they had a "create staged graph", "add series" X number of series, then finally graph.  The way I changed it (since this question) is to create a html tables first then graph on the html tables.  Doesn't really seem to help much.

Comment: You can do this. What you do is create an array to hold your series (which you already do) then just define your data in the chart builder code as `series: newSeries`. I got your times down to 25s (randomly with spikes to 60s). See: https://jsfiddle.net/6gbcdb4L/12/